# UIImage that won't disappear when removing it from its superview

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5, imagenamed

Under iOS 5, I encounter the following problem : the following code is called on a controller everytime a new product is picked in the application. It displays a bullet list of features in the controller's view.

Every bullet is an image that is added at the right place (in front of the corresponding text).

Now, the problem is that sometimes, apparently randomly, some bullets are not removed from the previous bullet lists, altough I remove it from its superview at the beginning of the methods.

```
  - (void) loadProduct{
    for (UIView * bullet in bullets){
        bullet.hidden = YES;
        [bullet removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [bullets removeAllObjects];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];


   ......here some stuff ......


    for (int i=0;i< numberOfFeatures;i++)
    {   

            UIImageView * bullet = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet.png"]];
            bullet.frame =CGRectMake(someFloatValue ,
                                     someOtherFloatValue,
                                     6,
                                     6);
            [self.view addSubview:bullet];

            [bullets addObject:bullet];
            [bullet release];

        }
    }
```

`bullets` is an NSMutableArray, a property of the controller.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your code seems fine. all the objects of bullets will be removed. When you some bullets are not removed, is it in the array or in display?

Comment: Thanks to babbidi, who hinted me about race conditions, I found the bug: the method was called twice almost simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bullets` it seems that you're only storing the labels:

```
[bullets addObject:label];
```

So, when removing everything from `bullets`, you're only removing the labels from the superview, the bullets (`UIImageView` controls) are left there.

It might be easier if you create a custom control (a view holding both the bullet and the label) and use those instead

Comment: You are totally right about the code that I initally posted, but this was just a mistake I made while simplifying the code to put in on SO. This error was not in the original code, and I edited it out of the code here.

Comment: I see, everything seems ok now. Are you removing objects from `bullets` from any other place? Another possible issue could be race conditions (this, only if you're accessing `bullets` from multiple threads).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remark about race conditions! I just put a breakpoint in the method, and it appears that it was called twice almost simultaneously under some conditions. That probably explains it. Thanks a lot. That said, I will delete the question, since it does not make much sense as is.